# Логирование тестов RestAssured

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Как правильно логировать тесты? Можно ли в лог вывести прошел тест или не прошел? И как это сделать? Нашел вот такое

```
RestAssured.filters(new ResponseLoggingFilter(LogDetail.ALL, fileOutPutStream),
                new RequestLoggingFilter(LogDetail.ALL, fileOutPutStream));
```

Работает, только непонятно прошел тест или не прошел. Если не прошел, то в консоль просто выбрасывает что тест не прошел потому то и по тому то, а в лог это не пишется

Comment: Прошел тест или не прошел должен определяться тестовым движком (test runner) например JUnit или TestNG. Определяет он это на основании выброшенного Exception/Error'а. Если в вашем тесте вы получили какой-то Response и выполняете у него проверку статус кода, например response.then().statusCode(200) и фактический код ответа не 200, то RestAssured бросит исключение и на этом моменте тест упадет, о чем вам уже в последствии сообщит Junit/TestNG и напишет об этом в логе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [org.junit.Rule](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html). Пример из живого проекта:

```
public static final Stopwatch STOPWATCH = new Stopwatch() {
    @Override
    protected void finished(long nanos, Description description) {
        String result = String.format("%-95s %7d", description.getDisplayName(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(nanos));
        results.append(result).append('\n');
        log.info(result + " ms\n");
    }
};
```

[org.junit.rules.Stopwatch](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/Stopwatch.html) имеет набор методов, которые запускаются :

- когда тест прошел проверку
- когда тест завалился
- когда тест закончился(с любым результатом)
- когда тест пропущен

Из [org.junit.runner.Description](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Description.html) можно достать информацию о методе:

- имя класс тестов
- имя запущенного метода (теста)
- Объект класса тестов `Class<?>`

В общем попробуйте а там поймете. `Rule` надо отмечать аннотациями на выбор:

- `@Rule` и они будут запускаться\создаваться для каждого теста.
- `@ClassRule` создаст правило для класса, т.е. одно на все тесты (аналог static поля или метода)